# jquery: cannot fetch the "value" attribute of a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, coffeescript

Here's a screenshot of my chrome javascript console demonstrating my dilemma.

[image: screenshot of my chrome javascript console demonstrating cannot fetch the "value" attribute of a div]

I seriously cannot understand why i can't fetch the "value" attribute.
The "class" attribute works just fine, so i figure the same should apply to "value".
The code (coffeescript) i'm testing in my app looks like this:

```
$ ->
  $(".comment").click ->
   alert $(this).attr 'value'
```

Neither this nor the code shown in this pic work.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong or what i SHOULD be doing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I just tried this with 1.6.2 and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `.val()`. This will work only on `select, input, textarea` tags. For other tags, `value` attribute is not valid.

If you're using latest jQuery, use `data-` attirbutes instead:

```
<div class="comment" data-value="64">

 var value = $('[div selector]').data('value');
```

Comment: How do i do it with a div then? Should i name the attribute something other than "value" and THEN use attr?

Comment: I see, thank you very much :) I did as you said and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `value` is special since its used for the value of form inputs and whatnot, I'm reading the jQuery source now to see exactly what's happening; but if you change it to `data-value` as would be [proper](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) in the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), that would likely work and would be standard.

Answer (score 0):

use some thing like this

$("div[data-request]").data() , This returns the object if you debug .