# How to set a div value correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I built a small order form for my website. When the user clicks on a `div` I would write the `value` of the `div` into a hidden `input` field. Also there will be a summary sheet where the values will be shown for the user to check his inputs.

The dummy works great with buttons. Now I want to transform every `button` into a `div` but it doesen´t work after that.

HTML:

```
<p style="background-color: yellow;">Order</p>
<br />
<div value="1" class="checkButton" id="writeBox">box1</div>
<button value="2" class="checkButton" id="writeBox">box2</button>
<br /><br />
<button value="6" class="checkButton" id="writePack">6 Monate</button>
<button value="12" class="checkButton" id="writePack">12 Monate</button>
<br /><br />
<button value="transfer" class="checkButton" id="writePayment">transfer</button>
<button value="paypal" class="checkButton" id="writePayment">paypal</button>
<button value="debit" class="checkButton" id="writePayment">debit</button>

<br /><br /><br />

<p style="background-color: yellow;">Hidden Input</p>
<br />
box <input type='text' value="" id="writeBoxForm"><br />
Paket <input type='text' value="" id="writePackForm"><br />
Bezahlart <input type='text' value="" id="writePaymentForm">

<br /><br /><br />

<p style="background-color: yellow;">Summary</p>
<br />
<span id="writePackSummary"></span> <span> - Monatspaket</span>
<br /><br />
<span>für box</span> <span id="writeBoxSummary"></span>
<br /><br />
<span>Zahlung per</span> <span id="writePaymentSummary"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".checkButton").click(function() {
var textForm = $( this ).val();
var textSummary = $( this ).val();
var summary = ('#'+this.id+'Summary');

$('#'+this.id+'Form').val(textForm);
$(summary).html(textSummary);

if ( $(this).text() == 'transfer' ) {
    $(summary).html('Überweisung');
} 
else if ( $(this).text() == 'paypal' ) {
    $(summary).html('PayPal');
}
else if ( $(this).text() == 'debit' ) {
    $(summary).html('Lastschrift');
}
});
```

I also have a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kKFJ3/2/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wow!! That is a piece of HTML. One thing (among many) you should not have two elements with the same ID in a page.

Comment: Yeah, its just a dummy ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887343/jquery-cannot-fetch-the-value-attribute-of-a-div

Comment: Div's don't have a `val()` property, you probably wanted `.text()` instead (or use a `data-value` attribute on the divs) and access with  `attr('data-value')`

Comment: The fist div in the fiddle is not working.

Comment: Gotcha. As `value` is not a valid HTML attribute for a `div`, you are better off using a `data-value` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` don't have `value` property.

```
var textForm = $(this).attr('value');
var textSummary = $(this).attr('value');
var summary = ('#' + this.id + 'Summary');
```

---

**ID of an element must be unique**

You can use a `data-*` property to fix it like

```
<div data-value="1" class="checkButton" data-target="writeBox">box1</div>
```

then

```
var $this = $(this);
var target = $this.data('target');
var textForm = $this.attr('value');
var textSummary = $this.attr('value');
var summary = ('#' + target + 'Summary');


$('#' + target + 'Form').val(textForm);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nW8uu/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use some data- on div like so:

```
<div class="checkButton" data-value="1" data-id="writeBox">box1</div>
```

And then:

```
var $this = $(this);
var textForm = $this.attr('data-value');
var id = $this.attr('data-id');
var summary = ('#' + id  + 'Summary');
```